# App build by Unity only have background color

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game works normally in the editor but when I tried to build it, it only got the default background color.

I have doing tried doing these things but none work:

- Build a completed old game, got the same problem. This game was built completely fine without problems before. I only go to "Build Settings" and press "Build", nothing in the game is changed so it still in the build-able state from before
- Add scene, remove scene, rebuild the whole scene
- Update SDK version to the latest

Answer (score 0):

What platform is active? Are you sure you haven't any errors in console after you're trying to start build?

Comment: + Platform is Android

+ Pretty sure there is no error since I un-tick the clear on build